# how to change row color of table in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

HI im working with vaadin,I have a table and im using the addItem Method to add items , what i want to do is at the moment of adding a new item i have to make some tests and set the color of the added row.

For example the resutlt of test is 1 then row color should be Red , and if the result is 2 row color should be green.

So any help how to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a CellStyleGenerator and apply it to all cells in one row.
More about CellStyleGenerator [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html#components.table.css).

Comment: Hey i tried it but didnt work for me , i dont know where's the problem : this is the code  
    table.setCellStyleGenerator(new   Table.CellStyleGenerator() {
         /**
       * 
        */
   private static final long   serialVersionUID   = -4891009429573146448L;

   public String getStyle(Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
       
       return "red";
      }
  }); 
and the css file : 
    @import "../reindeer/styles.css";

    .v-table-row-red {
 background: #FF0000;
 color: #000000;
    }

Comment: @user986586 I haven't tried your code but wondering why ".v-table-row" and not ".v-table-cell"?

Comment: hey thanks , ".v-table-row" is for the all one row and ".v-table-cell" for a cell , any way thanks the solution is working the problem was the name of the css file

Comment: @user986586 I didn't know that you can set a css property for a row out of a CellStyleGenerator.

Comment: and how would you change the color of the selected row?

Comment: @VasileSurdu Row styles are generated when porpertyId is null

Comment: @nexus yeah, i wanted the selected row though, i found i should overwrite the v.table v-selected in style css. Tnx